# unable to put TabView inside a ScrollView

Tags: swiftui

for some reason my images become super small when I have a scroll view as the parent. if i dont have a scrollview it works perfect

```
import SwiftUI

struct CarouselView: View {
    let dummyImageURLs = [
        URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/600/400")!,
        URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/600/400")!,
    
    ]

    @State private var currentIndex: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            TabView(selection: $currentIndex) {
                ForEach(0..<dummyImageURLs.count) { index in
                    AsyncImage(url: dummyImageURLs[index]) { phase in
                        switch phase {
                        case .empty:
                            ProgressView()
                        case .success(let image):
                            image
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFill() // Use .scaledToFill() to fill the available space
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                                .clipped()
                        case .failure:
                            Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle")
                        @unknown default:
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                    }
                    .tag(index)
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .automatic))
        }
    }
}
```

this is what it looks like with scroll view as a parent::

[image: with_scroll_view]

without scrollview::

[image: with_scroll_view]

i found this stackoverflow that appears to have the same issue but i dont know how to implement their fix.
[SwiftUI TabView inside a ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67610036/swiftui-tabview-inside-a-scrollview)

chatgpt is not helping either haha.

===updated===

this appeared to work::

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CarouselView()
    }
}
import SwiftUI

struct CarouselView: View {
    let dummyImageURLs = [
        URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/600/400")!,
        URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/600/400")!,
    ]

    @State private var currentIndex: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                TabView(selection: $currentIndex) {
                    ForEach(0..<dummyImageURLs.count) { index in
                        AsyncImage(url: dummyImageURLs[index]) { phase in
                            switch phase {
                            case .empty:
                                ProgressView()
                            case .success(let image):
                                image
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFill()
                                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                                    .clipped()
                            case .failure:
                                Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle")
                            @unknown default:
                                EmptyView()
                            }
                        }
                        .tag(index)
                    }
                }
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .automatic))
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CarouselView()
    }
}
```